# A basic calculation about line integral and multiple integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Here is the question: 
Suppose a function $f(x,y)$ is defined on the region $D:x^2+y^2\le1$. The second order partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous. $f$ satisfies:
$$ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}. $$
Calculate $\iint_D\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)dxdy.$
The answer(You can ignore what follows the red eqation):
Denote $L:x=\rho\cos \theta,y=\rho \sin \theta$.The direction of $L$ is counterclockwise.$D_1$ is region enclosed by $L$.
Then

\begin{align*}\label{2}
  & \iint_D\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)dxdy\\
  =& 
\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1\left(\rho\cos \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\rho\sin \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\rho d\rho \\
  =& \color{red}{\int_0^1\rho d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\rho\cos \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\rho\sin \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)d\theta}\\
  =& \int_0^1\left(\int_L -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dy\right)\rho d\rho \\
  =&\int_0 ^1 \left[\iint_{D_1}\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)dxdy\right]\rho d\rho \\
 =&\int_0^1\left[\iint_{D_1}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy\right]\rho d\rho \\
 =&\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^\rho e^{-r^2}rdr\right)\rho d\rho \\
 =&\int_0^1\pi\left(1-e^{-\rho^2}\right)\rho d\rho \\
 =&\frac{\pi}{2e}.
\end{align*}
So my confusion is:
Why I cannot extract the factor $\rho$?
\begin{align*}\label{3}
 & \color{red}{\int_0^1\rho d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\rho\cos \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\rho\sin \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)d\theta}\\
 =&\int_0^1\rho^2 d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\cos \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\sin \theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)d\theta \\
 =&\int_0^1\rho^2 d\rho \left(\int_C -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dy\right) \text{($C$ is the unit circle)}\\
 =&\frac{1}{3}\iint_C e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy \\
 =&\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^1 e^{-r^2}rdr
\end{align*}
The answer is wrong, but I don't know why my answer is not correct. Can someone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: We cannot ignore the part that follows the red because it looks correct. The mistake you make is that you pull out $\rho$ from the inner integral and think that was it but the function you integrate depends on $\color{red}\rho\cos\theta$ and $\color{red}\rho\sin\theta\,.\;$ :)

Comment: @KurtG. But I think $\rho$ is a variable independent of $\theta$, so I think pilling out $\rho$ from the inner integral is correct.

Comment: Only if $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ do not depend on $\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta\,.$ But they do. Simplifying the notation is not always the best idea. Revisit the calculation of line integrals in general. Forget about this particular example.

Comment: Check what happens for some $f$ that need not satisfy the PDE, such as $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-1}{y}$. Take the derivatives and replace $(x,y)=(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)$. You will not be able to factor out every instance of $\rho$ like you want.